# Encoding issue when inserting .mdb data into SQL

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, pdo

I'm trying to export the contents of a .mdb file (from Microsoft Access) into a MySQL database.

When I get the content out of the .mdb file and echo it to the page it appears fine, like standard text. However when I go to INSERT it into the database using PDO I get an `incorrect string value` error. The string appears like this in the INSERT clause:

```
\x41\x44\x20\x2d\x20\x57\x49\x4c\x44\x20\x42\x45\x41\x4e\x20\x43\x41\x46\xc9
```

I'm not totally sure why this is happening, or what I need to do to rectify it. It doesn't happen with all records, only some.

Any pointers would be helpful.

**SOLUTION**

Because the data is coming from a Microsoft Access DB it contained Microsoft Office special characters which were invalid in UTF-8. So I parsed each string with the following function.

```
iconv("cp1252","UTF-8", $str);
```

Comment: *tap, tap, tap....crystal ball enlighten me.....*. The crystal ball said that we would need to see your code in order to help you. Anything else would be pure speculation.

Comment: Kind of hard to do, I'm using `Bolt` which runs on top of `Symfony`. So there's a lot of code to it.

Comment: Drat. That's going to make this hard to figure out. View the source of the page output to see if it is encoded there and being interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Tried that too, but it just looks like plain text.

Comment: GOT IT! Microsoft encoded characters. That's what's messing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have quotes or other special characters in some text fields. Escape the text before insert with

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($text)
  // or
mysql_real_escape_string($text)
```

**SEE OP FOR ACTUAL SOLUTION**

Comment: I'm using PDO within the Symfony framework, so that will escape the strings for me.

Comment: Accepted as it triggered my brain to look for MS specific characters.